# Android application failing to connect to port 80

Tags: android

I am using this url in android application code as I am using genymotion.

```
String login_url = "http:// 10.0.3.2:8080/login.php";
```

But the exception in Logcat says

```
-java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I am not able to resolve this issue.

When I try to execute login.php separately.It runs on `http://127.0.0.1/login.php`

Comment: share tailing code inc. connection/client

Comment: which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a real device?

Comment: She mentioned genymotion

Comment: Is the internet in the emulator working? Try opening a browser in genymotion and browse something

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I got the answer.There was a space in my url,which was incorrect.

So,For running it on genymotion emulator use url--->

```
String login_url = `"http://10.0.3.2:8080/login.php";`
```

And for android device use--->`

```
String login_url = "http://192.168.*.*/login.php";`
```